# Example of textAlign: 'justify'

Tags: react-native

Does anyone have a working example or an explanation of how `textAlign: 'justify'` works in React Native? Also curious about `textAlign: 'auto'`

Answer (score 0):

In fact react native does not support justify align for text in android OS . the only way is using Webview react native tag as follow :

```
<View style={  flex: 1,height: 500}}}>
        <WebView
          source={{
            html:
              "<style>p{text-align:justify}</style>" +
              "<p>" +
              "Lorem Ipsum is sim and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum" +
              "</p>"
          }}
        />
      </View>
```

Answer (score -3):

I believe your only textAlign: options in react native are 'center', 'flext-start' and 'flex-end'